# Google Spreadsheet API - Java - com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Spreadsheet API in my simple Android application. This is the piece of code:

```
URL spreadSheetUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery(spreadSheetUrl);
query.setTitleQuery("xyz");
query.setTitleExact(true);
SpreadsheetFeed spreadSheetFeed = service.getFeed(query, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
```

This piece of code is called from my application's sync adapter.

I am getting this error:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary
com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2136)
com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676)
com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1034)
```

Can someone suggest how I can solve this issue?

Comment: No idea about this one error. But there is advice on Stackoverflow about setting up the connection.

Comment: same here have u got answer of this problem but dont like serusercredentials

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that I did not set the user credentials before executing this piece of code.

```
service.setUserCredentials(user, password);
```

Adding this line helped solve this issue. Weird.

Comment: What a completely-useless error-message. Google's documentation is seriously lacking.

Comment: Agreed!
I love Google, but they don't do very well at writing documentation

Comment: FYI, this answer is no longer valid. The old user/password authentication does not work anymore. You need to use OAuth2.

Comment: @TimoLehto is right. You might be getting this exception if you are not using OAuth2: `com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name) at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:688)
 at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)`

Comment: what is the username and password in this case?